# C: 2 User input fields when requesting 3

Tags: c

From what I understand I should be getting 3 user input prompts, Trip Distance, Car MPG, and Gas Dollars Per Gallon to calculate total trip cost. Whenever I run the code, I only get prompted to input trip distance and car mpg, it skips gas dpg. How do I get it to recognize 3 user inputs?

```c
int main() {
    int miles;
    double milesPG;
    double dollarsPG;
    double gasCost = (miles * (1.0 / milesPG) * dollarsPG);

    printf("Input trip distance: ", miles);
    scanf("%d", &miles);

    printf("\nInput car miles per gallon: ", milesPG);
    scanf("%0.2lf", &milesPG);

    printf("\nInput gas dollars per gallon: ", dollarsPG);
    scanf("%0.2lf", &dollarsPG);

    printf("\nTotal trip cost is %0.2lf \n", gasCost);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: @EOF it's quite possible, in our case, OP does not know C++ well enough to understand your comment.  
Could you edit it and make it more simple to understand for the OP?

Comment: @pratikpc The OP's level of understanding of c++ seems immaterial to my comment. Furthermore, I cannot conceive of a clearer and more authoritative comment than a C-standard quote. Frankly, I find it unlikely that anybody would have any problem understanding the comment.

Comment: @pratikpc your explanation and going through the code line by line was a huge help! I really wanted trip distance to be a user input variable, but my professor basically said no and to make multiple printf statements for 10, 50, and 400 miles. It didn't make sense to me considering if this were to be part of an actual program, I'd want the user to necessitate the variables. I digress, thank you so much again!

Comment: @EOF Thank you for trying to explain it to the best of your ability, teaching isn't everyone's strong suit.

Comment: @BrysonSherman Just like programming! (and general reading comprehension).

Comment: @BrysonSherman If you look at my profile, you may notice that I *do* occasionally provide answers to questions. While I generally write rather too terse answers, I'd like to think that my answers typically solve the problem stated in the question (or at least clarify how to avoid the problem). However, I generally only answer question that display at least *some* minimal effort at understanding the problem.

Comment: @EOF Look man, whatever validation you're after I hope you find it. You're not going to get it from a student that's 2 weeks into Intro to C. Not everyone is going to have your level of understanding, so your "clarification" may not be received by the intended audience, which is arguably the point in teaching. From what I understand, Stack Overflow's mantra is, "...most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge." Unless my comprehension isn't as fine tuned as yours, I understood that as all levels of learning, not"Forum for programmers of 6+ years."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not include `<stdio.h>`
- you compute `gasCost` **before** the values of `miles`, `milesPG` and `dollarsPG` are input. Since these variables are uninitialized, this has undefined behavior.
- passing the uninitialized values to the `printf()` statements for prompting is useless and actually has undefined behavior as these variables are uninitialized.
- the conversion format `"%0.2lf"` is invalid for `scanf()`. You cannot specify how many places to input, just the maximum number of bytes to read, which is not useful in your case.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int miles;
    double milesPG;
    double dollarsPG;

    printf("Input trip distance: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &miles) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("\nInput car miles per gallon: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &milesPG) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("\nInput gas dollars per gallon: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &dollarsPG) != 1)
        return 1;

    double gasCost = (miles * (1.0 / milesPG) * dollarsPG);
    printf("\nTotal trip cost is %.2f\n", gasCost);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: printf("Input trip distance: ", miles);
Putting miles in the printf is somewhat useless as well

Comment: @pratikpc: good point! this actually has undefined behavior in this particular case :)